# Why does Django 1.7 tell me that the csrf_token was not provided in the context after sending a successful ajax request?

Tags: ajax, django, csrf, django-1.7, django-csrf

When I get the template and render a form in my Django 1.7 app, I get no errors on the Python server console. I can submit the form using AJAX using the X-CSRFHeader recommendation provided in the Django documentation, and the request is successful and does not throw a 403 forbidden. I can even submit this form again with different information (which is desired behaviour) and still have success.

What concerns me is that after the first POST request, The console shows:

```
UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value. This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.'
```

The first time the template is rendered, it renders it using `render(request, 'appname/index.html', context)`, which I understand should include the same information that `RenderContext()` provides in a more efficient method.

Does anybody have any idea about what might be going wrong?

My ajax code:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
  // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
  return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
function sameOrigin(url) {
  // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
  // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
  var host = document.location.host; // host + port
  var protocol = document.location.protocol;
  var sr_origin = '//' + host;
  var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
  // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
  return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
      (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
      // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
      !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}
$(function(){
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
            // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
            // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

// Define ajax submit function
$('.tab-pane form').submit(function (event){
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: new FormData($('.tab-pane.active form').get(0)),
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
      // Re-enable submit button
      $(".submit-btn").removeClass("disabled");
      $(".cancel-btn").removeClass("disabled");

      // Show errors or clean and reset form
      $('.tab-pane.active form div:first').replaceWith(data['form_html']);

      if (data['success']) {
        // Close modal
        $('#incidentForm').modal('hide');

        // Add point to map
        var point = geojsonMarker(JSON.parse(data['point']), data['point_type'])
        point.bindPopup(getPopup(point.getLayers()[0]));
        incidentData.addLayer(point);

        // Pan to point
        map.setView(point.getBounds().getCenter(), 18, {'animate': true});
        setTimeout(function(){
          point.openPopup();
        }, 300);

        // Print success or failure message
        var message = "<strong>" + '{% trans "Thank you!" %}' + "</strong><br>" + '{% trans "Your incident marker was successfully added." %}';
        showMessage(message);
      }
    }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
})
```

My view method is the following:

```
@require_POST
def postTheft(request):
     return postPoint(request, TheftForm)

def postPoint(request, Form):
    """Submit a user point submission to the database. Normalize geometry and activate push notifications."""
    form = Form(request.POST)
    form.data = form.data.copy()

# Convert coords to valid geometry
try:
    form.data['geom'] = normalizeGeometry(form.data['geom'])
except(ValueError):
    messages.error(request, '<strong>' + _('Error') + '</strong><br>' + _('No point was selected for this type of report.'))

# Validate and submit to db
if form.is_valid():
    point = form.save()
    # Errors with push notifications should not affect reporting
    if not settings.DEBUG:
        try: pushNotification.pushNotification(point)
        except: pass

    return JsonResponse({
        'success': True,
        'point': GeoJSONSerializer().serialize([point,]),
        'point_type': point.p_type,
        'form_html': render_crispy_form(Form())
    })
else:
    logger.debug("Form not valid")

# Else: error occurred
form.data['geom'] = form.data['geom'].json
form_html = render_crispy_form(form)
return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'form_html': form_html})
```

Code that renders the initial template:

```
def index(request, lat=None, lng=None, zoom=None):
incidents = Incident.objects.select_related('point').all()

context = {
    # Model data used by map
    'collisions': incidents.filter(p_type__exact="collision"),
    'nearmisses': incidents.filter(p_type__exact="nearmiss"),
    'hazards': Hazard.objects.select_related('point').all(),
    'thefts': Theft.objects.select_related('point').all(),
    "geofences": AlertArea.objects.filter(user=request.user.id),

    # Form data used by map
    "incidentForm": IncidentForm(),
    "geofenceForm": GeofenceForm(),
    "hazardForm": HazardForm(),
    "theftForm": TheftForm(),

    "editForm": EditForm()
}

# Add zoom and center data if present
if not None in [lat, lng, zoom]:
    context['lat']= float(lat)
    context['lng']= float(lng)
    context['zoom']= int(zoom)

return render(request, 'mapApp/index.html', context)
```

Comment: What is the `render_crispy_form` method? If it's rendering the form with a csrf token, then I would expect it to take the `request` as an argument.

Comment: You don't seem to have shown the code that renders the template in the first place.

Comment: render_crispy_form is a method that renders django modelforms as nice bootstrap html. It includes a `{% csrf_token %}` tag automatically, but this can be disabled. I've disabled it since I'm using the X-CSRFHeader header on all my post requests.

Comment: Edited the question to include my initial template rendering

Answer (score 0):

I messed up when disabling the csrf_tag in my django crispy_forms template. So, the csrf token was available as a header, but render_crispy_form was trying to render the csrf token even though it wasn't there when passed back from the JsonResponse.

Alasdair's comment pointed me in the right direction.
Thanks for the help everyone!